# Kendo UI DropDownListFor value cannot be null binding error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following Kendo UI DropDownListFor in my MVC 4 application and I'm getting a value cannot be null error when I submit.

```
@Html.Kendo()
.DropDownListFor(m => m.JobTitle)
.BindTo(ViewData["Jobs"] as SelectList)
```

Typically I would use a viewmodel to handle the binding but in this case that's not an option so I'm attempting to populate my list with a ViewData list. The list loads fine into the dropdown list but it is not associating my selection with the JobTitle value. Any advice on this would be much appreciated as I've tried everything I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you specified DataTextField() and DataValueField() properties for the wrapper?

e.g.

```
         @Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.JobTitle)
                                                .OptionLabel("Select Job Title...")
                                                .DataTextField("text")
                                                .DataValueField("value")
.BindTo(ViewData["Jobs"] as SelectList)
```

Update:

```
    List<SelectListItem> JobTitles = new List<SelectListItem>();
    JobTitles.Add(new SelectListItem { Value="One", Text = "One"});
    JobTitles.Add(new SelectListItem { Value="Two", Text = "Two"});  
    JobTitles.Add(new SelectListItem { Value="Three", Text = "Three"});
    JobTitles.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Four", Text = "Four" });
    SelectList jobs = new SelectList(JobTitles, "value","text");
    ViewData["Jobs"] = jobs;
```

Update 2:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.JobTitle)
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("JobTitlesList").OptionLabel("Select Job Title...").Events(e => {
                e.Change("listChange");
            }).BindTo(new SelectList((IEnumerable<string>)ViewData["Jobs"])))


//JScript event handler

function listChange(e) 
  {
     //console.log(e);
     $('#JobTitle').val(e.sender.text());
  }
```

Comment: That would work if I wanted to hard code the options but it won't associate my list with the value. The list comes out of a database so I don't want to type those values into the code itself.

Comment: To clarify, the DataValueField takes a string and my values are in a list so I'm not sure how to make that work in this case.

Comment: OK, to clarify, so the server is returning a SelectList and there is no way you can make it return simply an IEnumerable instead?

Comment: BindTo() takes an IEnumerable<SelectList> so it is, and it works fine for the binding... the dropdownlist shows the values it should and everything looks great. The issue, as you mentioned in your initial answer, is that it looks at the text and data values differently. It recognizes my items as the text but not as the value and I don't know how to set that in this scenario.

Comment: I will update my answer with an initialization of a select list, could you confirm if the object you're passing in ViewData["Jobs"] is similar?

Comment: All that is getting passed in is a list of strings that it reads as the options in the dropdownlist.

Comment: You're still thinking about it in terms of manually adding in the values with Value="whatever". I can do this but I'd like it to be done dynamically.

Comment: OK so another solution, assuming you're just passing a list of strings to the view and setting it as a SelectList is to not bind the list to the model, but use a hidden field and then change the value of the hidden field when the list option is changed. I'll update my answer with example code...

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you for your help, I hadn't thought of doing it like that.

Answer (score 5):

I also had the same problem when I omitted to specify the `Name` property.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but I had to use `as IEnumerable` instead of `SelectList` to get it working.

```
                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                    .Name("ControlName")
                    .DataValueField("value")
                    .DataTextField("text")
                    .BindTo(ViewData["UnitList"] as IEnumerable)
```

In the controller, ViewData is populated like this:

```
ViewData["prodUnits"] = 
DbHelper.GetUnitList("Stuff");
```

and DbHelper looks like this:

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<Object> GetUnitList(string thing)
    {
        using (var Db = new dbEntities())
        {
            return (from obj in Db.Units
                    where obj.things == thing
                    select new
                    {
                        value = obj.Unit_ID,
                        text = obj.Unit_Name
                    }).ToList().Distinct().OrderBy(obj => obj.value);
        }


    }
```

I'll be honest and say I do not understand this and the error gave me absolutely no clue Somehow it looks like the type if IEnumerable has been preserved through ViewData..

Comment: I tried most of the different suggestions on how to do this, and this is the one that worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this : code

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
 .DataTextField("Text")
              .DataValueField("Value")
              .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
              new SelectListItem() {
                  Text = "Select",
                  Value = null
              },
              new SelectListItem() {
                  Text = "Yes",
                  Value = true.ToString()
              },
              new SelectListItem() {
                  Text = "No",
                  Value = false.ToString()
              }
          })
.HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = "true" }))
```

Any suggestion : vishalroxx7@gmail.com